# Prevent Monit from starting a process on a machine restart

Tags: monit

We have around 100 daemon processes started by monit. All these processes are CPU intensive during the initial phase of their processing i.e. the bootstrapping is CPU intensive.

In case of a machine restart all the 100 processes start at the same time and the CPU load average goes really high and eventually bring the machine down again.

We have a script which starts these processes one by one by pausing for 5-10 minutes after each process start, to give time for the started process to get its initial CPU time.

Is there a way in monit to avoid starting a process after the machine reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirements in the past and have used the "depends on" option in monit; i.e., this monitor is not triggered unless the one it depends on is "up" (green).